# SQL: lookup for UUID

Tags: sql

I have my user table (pseudo sql, because I use an ORM and I must support several different DB types):

```
id: INTEGER, PK, AUTOINCREMENT
UUID : BINARY(16) (inserted by an update, it's a hash(id) )
```

I am currently using id for FK in all other tables.
However, in my REST API, I have to serve informations with the UUID, which causes a problem later to query.

Should I:

- FK on the UUID instead?
- just lookup id(UUID) each time (fast thanks to cache mechanism after a while)?

Comment: you could just go with your second option..if you are really worried about speeds..index ur id and uuid together..its not good to touch the integrity of data models..if an FK is meant to be an FK..let it be!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it is better to use the auto-incremented id for the foreign key reference rather than some other combination of unique columns.

One important reason is that indexes on a single integer are more efficient than indexes on other column types -- if for no other reason than the index being smaller, so it occupies less disk and less memory.  Also, there is additional overhead to storing the longer UUID in secondary tables.

This is not the only consideration.  Another consideration is that you could change the UUID, if necessary, without changing the foreign key references.  For instance, you may wake up one day and say "that id has to start with AAA".  You can alter the table and update the table and be done with it -- or you could worry about foreign key references as well.  Or, you might add an organization column and decide that the unique key is a combination of the UUID and organization.  These operations are much harder/slower if the UUID is being used as a foreign key reference.

When you have composite primary keys (more than one column), using the auto-incremented id is an even better idea.  In this case, using the id for joins prevents mistakes where one of the join conditions might be left out.

As you point out, looking up the UUID for a given id should be a fast operation with the correct indexes.  There may be some borderline cases where you would not want to have an id, but in general, it is a good idea.